# awk check if value from a column in file A exists in file B and if not print whole line of file A

Tags: linux, awk

fileA:

```
date;numberX;descX;numberY
08-03-2021;5618452029952;TEXT;2250630000000
08-03-2021;5618452029952;TEXT;2250660000000
08-03-2021;5618452029952;TEXT;2250670000000
08-03-2021;5618452029952;TEXT;2250700000000
08-03-2021;5618452029952;TEXT;2250760000000
```

fileB:

```
2250630000000
2250670000000
2250700000000
2250760000000
```

I want to check if numberY (column 4) from fileA exists in fileB (which just has 1 column no ;), if not then I want the whole line of fileA printed, so not the matches.

so it should show

```
08-03-2021;5618452029952;TEXT;2250660000000
```

I thought I was close getting this to work with awk but am missing something somewhere.

Thank you for your answers.

addon: I started of by seeing if I could find the matches but even that seems to fail:

```
awk -F \; 'NR == FNR { a[$0]; next } ($4 in a)' fileB fileA
```

addon:  added sample file

Comment: _I want to check if numberY from fileA exists in fileB, **if not** then I want the whole line of fileA printed, so not the matches._ Please, add another line to `fileA` which has `$4` that does not exist in `fileB` and show the expected output. Also, you have [tag:linux] tagged but are you sure the files do not have windows newlines (\r\n instead of Linux bare \n)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='\r?\n' 'FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} !($4 in arr)' fileB FS=";" fileA
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v RS='\r?\n' '    ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{               ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when fileB is being read.
  arr[$0]              ##Creating array arr with current line index.
  next                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
!($4 in arr)           ##Checking condition if 4th column of fileA is present in arr then print line.
' fileB FS=";" fileA   ##Mentioning Input_file(s) and setting FS=";" before fileA.
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but sadly this gives no results

Comment: @Calan, with your shown samples it has worked fine for me, are your files same as shown samples/

Comment: _no results_ is correct according to the requirement _check if value from a column in file A exists in file B and **if not** print whole line_.

Comment: @Armali, oh ok, could you please try my edited code now and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: I don't know what or when OP wants output but Windows newlines in `fileB` would break every solution.

Comment: @JamesBrown, yeah I agree on it, I have changed the solution now, let me know sir if this looks ok to you, cheers :)

Comment: Added some sample
Just tested your new code, works like a charm :)   Thank you very much